# How to load and replace images using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, zend-framework, zend-framework2

So i developed a **zend framework** application with doctrine ORM, and in one of my view i want to load images when i press my input file and chose a new image, this a picture describe what i want : 
[image]

this is a part of my view :

```
<li>
     <label>Url:</label>
  <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary" onclick="load_image">
     <span>Upload New Image</span>
     <input type="file" name="url" class="upload" value="<?php echo $article->getImage()->getUrl(); ?>" required>
  </div>
  </li>
 // here i show my image
  <li style="float:right">
   <img class="img-responsive img-border img-thumbnail" src="../../../upload/<?php echo $article->getImage()->getUrl(); ?>" alt="" id="image">
  </li>
```

so please if someone has any idea i will be very apreciative

Comment: You will want to use `FileReader` as stated in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799246/displaying-image-after-choose-file-before-upload

Comment: You cannot programmatically set the value of a file input.